# Subscribe to multiple OPC-UA nodes at once

Tags: opc, opc-ua, node-opcua

I need to subscribe to ~1000 nodes, which were created in a hierarchy, like:

> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E01.Ambient.Temperature
>
> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E01.Ambient.WindDir
>
> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E01.Commands.AckAllErrors
>
> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E03.Ambient.Temperature
>
> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E03.Ambient.WindDir
>
> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E03.Ambient.WindSpeed

I am treating every update the same way, thus calling `subscription.monitor()` function for each of them and creating a new callback function does not seem to be the optimal way to me.

Is it possible to subscribe to multiple nodes with a pattern, e.g all nodes that fall under:

> ns=2;s=0:Manufacturing.E01.

Answer (score 6):

No it is not - 
There is no way to subscribe to a "folder" in OPC UA.

The easiest way to proceed in your case will be to first browse the Folders by using the OPC UA **Browse** Service.

The OPC UA Server will return you all the references from the asked Starting Node (OPC UA Parent-Children references might be *Organizes*, *HasComponent*, Has *Property*,...).

Then you can use the OPC UA **CreateSubscription**/**CreateMonitoredItems** Services to subscribe to the Nodes.

Comment: Is there a limit in the number of subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, there is. It's specific to the configuration of your server. Please note that you don't have to create a new subscription for every monitored item.